# Error on displaying form error in a table with scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, django

I have form a table with lot of entries. While getting the form error on form submit, the error is not displayed in visible region. There is a need to scroll down to the table.

Can anybody help me to fix it.

I'm using Django form submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, but I fixed it using JQuery.

`$('.errorlist').get(0).scrollIntoView();`